# not able to display the aggregation values in meteor template

Tags: meteor, aggregation

I am able to get the aggreate values from server to client, but could not display it on the template. Am i missing something here.Appreciate your help.Iam a newbie in meteor.

//client side javascript

```
Template.DashboardCategoriesChart.helpers({
    'CategoryAggregateItem':function(){
        var res;
        Meteor.call("getAggregateCategoriesSum",function(errors,results){
            console.log("results value: "+ JSON.stringify(results))
            return results ;
        };
    };
});
```

//stringfy value returned

```
results value: [
    {"_id":"Household","totalAmount":420},
    {"_id":"Insurance","totalAmount":235},
    {"_id":"Family","totalAmount":1358},
    {"_id":"Utilities","totalAmount":5371.5},
    {"_id":"Automobile","totalAmount":500},
    {"_id":"Home Office","totalAmount":290},
    {"_id":"Travel","totalAmount":14},
    {"_id":"Food","totalAmount":303}
]
```

//Template

```
{{#each  CategoryAggregateItem}}
    <tr> 
        <td>{{_id}}</td><td>{{totalAmount}}</td> 
    </tr> 

{{/each}}
```

Comment: Why did you put 'CategoryAggregateItem' in quotation marks?

Comment: i think its part of the template helper format, aplogies iam new bie, correct me if iam wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your client side javascript to this:

```
Template.DashboardCategoriesChart.onCreated(function () {
  _this = this;
  _this.CategoryAggregateItem = new ReactiveVar(null);
  Meteor.call("getAggregateCategoriesSum",function(errors,results){
    console.log("results value: "+ JSON.stringify(results))
    _this.CategoryAggregateItem.set(results);
  }
});

Template.DashboardCategoriesChart.helpers({
  'CategoryAggregateItem':function(){
    return Template.instance().CategoryAggregateItem.get();
  });
```

When the Callback from `Meteor.Call` is triggered, it will update the `ReactiveVar`.  This causes the template to rerender and display the retrieved data.
You may also want to provide alternative markup in your template for when the helper returns `null`, before the data is received by the client.

Comment: i have done as per the instructions, but getting the following error.
Exception in delivering result of invoking 'getAggregateCategoriesSum': TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
    at http://localhost:3000/app/client/templates/Dashbaord/DashboardCategoriesChart.js?37343599d176c14e479ee65d1e6f6b12042fb362:37:29
    at null._callback (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?637cc835a2ee4a2302a010c9a4c97b906db5f41c:1007:22)
    at _.extend._maybeInvokeCallback (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?82da06d8e1ea6342d823b2c5c3be071e96108c70:3508:12)

Comment: ahh, sorry, `this` is not the same in the callback.  I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked, thanks a ton JeremyK for leading to right direction.

```
 Template.DashboardCategoriesChart.helpers({
'CategoryAggregateItem':function(){
    return Template.instance().CategoryAggregateItem.get(); //this.CategoryAggregateItem;
    }
});
Template.DashboardCategoriesChart.onCreated(function () {
    var instance = this;
    this.CategoryAggregateItem = new ReactiveVar(null);
    Meteor.call("getAggregateCategoriesSum",function(errors,results){
    console.log("results value: "+ JSON.stringify(results))
    instance.CategoryAggregateItem.set(results);
    })
})
```